# How to get a Facebook user's ID?

Tags: php, facebook

I followed this tutorial: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
on how to setup Facebook authentication using php (server-side implementation). I can get a access token back from Facebook but how do I get the Facebook user ID of the user who has logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use facebook PHP SDK:
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

See the example file in order not to get Lost...
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Facebook graph API is kinda annoying... so using this will be easier (at least for me)

Comment: This worked. Took a minute to setup but easily provided me the user's ID.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, if your framework/sdk/whatever doesn't provide it for you, would be to query https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=....

Comment: That works in the browser URL but if I try it in cURL I get this:    {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating application."}}

Comment: I wanted the id and the name so I used https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name&access_token=....

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick non-programatic way of getting your user-id, it's in your browser cookie called `c_user` I believe